# Предупреждения при сборки библиотеки alglib в qt4.7.8 версия gcc 7

Tags: c++, qt

Подключил библиотеку alglib к qt. Сделав следующие:

1. Создал директорию alglib
2. Разместил в директории все .c и .h файлы.
3. Создал .pri. Добавил в него:

   ## -----------------------------------------------------------

   ```
               # operate objects
               # -----------------------------------------------------------

              INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD

              # Header files
               HEADERS += $$PWD/alglibinternal.h \
                          $$PWD/alglibmisc.h \
                          $$PWD/ap.h \
                          $$PWD/dataanalysis.h \
                          $$PWD/diffequations.h \
                          $$PWD/fasttransforms.h \
                          $$PWD/integration.h \
                          $$PWD/interpolation.h \
                          $$PWD/linalg.h \
                          $$PWD/optimization.h \
                          $$PWD/solvers.h \
                          $$PWD/specialfunctions.h \
                          $$PWD/statistics.h \
                          $$PWD/stdafx.h 



             # Source files
             SOURCES += $$PWD/alglibinternal.cpp \
                        $$PWD/alglibmisc.cpp \
                        $$PWD/ap.cpp \
                        $$PWD/dataanalysis.cpp \
                        $$PWD/diffequations.cpp \
                        $$PWD/fasttransforms.cpp \
                        $$PWD/integration.cpp \
                        $$PWD/interpolation.cpp \
                        $$PWD/linalg.cpp \
                        $$PWD/optimization.cpp \
                        $$PWD/solvers.cpp \
                        $$PWD/specialfunctions.cpp \
                        $$PWD/statistics.cpp
   ```
4. Добавил в .pro файл "include(alglib/alglib.pri)"
5. Запустил сборку и получил кучу [предупреждений](https://yadi.sk/d/7DhnUXV4mueJfg):

   ```
    ../Tion-pro28/alglib/alglibinternal.cpp: In function ‘alglib_impl::ae_int_t 
    alglib_impl::getrdfserializationcode(alglib_impl::ae_state*)’:
     ../Tion-pro28/alglib/alglibinternal.cpp:381:44: warning: unused parameter ‘_state’ [-Wunused- 
     parameter]
     ae_int_t getrdfserializationcode(ae_state *_state)
                                           ^~~~~~
   ```

Добавил в .pro строчку `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wno-unused-variable` пересобрал, но предупреждения остались.

В ссылки есть лог с полным списком предупреждений. Как убрать эти предупреждения?

Comment: У QMAKE_CXX... нет такого флага для отключения предупреждений. Это флаг для компилятора и его надо устанаваливать в настройках проекта

https://progi.pro/gcc-ignoriruet-wno-unused-variable-2981215

Comment: Можно более подробно в какие настройки проекта нужно установить данный флаг?

Comment: Поищите в настройках проекта компилятор - там же есть поле для ввода его флагов

Comment: То есть смотрите, у вас есть комплект (компилятор, дебаггер и т.д.). Вы можете его продублировать, переназвать (типа, комплект с флагами) и добавить к нему соответствующие флаги, а дальше выбрать этот комплект в настройках вашего проекта https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-tool-chains.html

Comment: У меня есть compilers ---> manual ---> c и c++ (добавил компилятор из buildroot). В с и c++ есть platform codegen flags и platform linker flags. Флаг -Wno-unused-variable куда добавлять в platform codegen flags или platform linker flags ?

Comment: Линкеру этот флаг точно не нужен

Comment: Добавил в platform codegen flags флаг -Wno-unused-variable предупреждения  не пропали, добавил -Wunused-parameter вместо  -Wno-unused-variable не помогло. Пробовал в .pro QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_OFF -= -Wunused-parameter не помогло.

Comment: Добавил:  QMAKE_CFLAGS += -Wno-unused-parameter  
QMAKE_CFLAGS -= -Wunused-parameter  
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wno-unused-parameter  
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -= -Wunused-parameter  
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON += -Wno-unused-parameter  
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON -= -Wunused-parameter  
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_OFF += -Wunused-parameter  
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_OFF -= -Wno-unused-parameter  предупреждения ушли но не все часть остались. Прикрепил в файл выше по ссылки.

Comment: Еще вот такие предупреждения  остались warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
 xdebugrecord1::xdebugrecord1() : _xdebugrecord1_owner() ,i(p_struct->i),c(*((alglib::complex*)(&p_struct->c))),a(&p_struct->a)